# f:param not set during second ajax call

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have simple datatable (Primefaces). In this table the last column contains a button which should set a param (f:param). I'm using p:commandButton with ajax="true" parameter. The button is binded to action (method in managed bean). Everything is fine until I click the button in the datatable second time. Why is that ?

The code looks like:

```
<p:dataTable id="zones" value="#{appointmentForm.matchingZones}"
             var="zone" paginator="true" rows="10"
             paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
             emptyMessage="#{msg['label.noAvailableZones']}">
    <p:column headerText="#{msg['label.choose']}">
        <p:commandButton value="#{msg['label.choose']}"
                         actionListener="#{appointmentForm.handleChosenZone}" process="@this"
                         update=":verificationForm" ajax="true">
            <f:param name="zoneId" value="#{zone.id}"/>
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:datatable>
```

When I click a button in whichever row the first time the param is set properly but during second time I'm getting NullPointerException.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What scope is your managed bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in a wrong place. Zone is a subclass of BaseEntity which contains Id, creation date etc

In case you use BaseEntity or something like that make sure you remember about serialization. In my case I had Zone:

```
public class Zone extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

And BaseEntity:

```
public class BaseEntity {
    @ID
    @GeneratedValue
    protected Long id;
    ...
}
```

So the id field was not serialized. Solution is to add public class BaseEntity **implements Serializable**.